# Type mismatch:could not convert from int to boolean

Tags: java, eclipse, boolean, type-mismatch

In the `if` statement, within the argument I get an error saying "type mismatch, could not convert from int to boolean". Please provide a solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sathya1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
    int x = (sathya1.nextInt());
    int y = (sathya1.nextInt());
    int addition = x+y;
    int subtraction = x-y;
    int multiplication = x*y;
    float division = x/y;       
    if(sathya1.nextInt(addition){
        System.out.println("The number is " +addition);
        elseif(sathya1.nextInt(subtraction)){
            System.out.println("The number is " +subtraction);
            elseif(sathya1.nextInt(multiplication)){
                System.out.println("The number is " +multiplication);
                elseif(sathya.1nextInt(division)){
                    System.out.println("The number is " +division);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Uppercase is perceived as SCREAMING and thus perceived RUDE.

Comment: Beyond: if if nextInt() would return a boolean (which it does NOT!) ... you are missing a closing ) there.

Comment: Also `elseif` is not a Java command. And `else` blocks do not go inside their preceding `if` block.

Comment: It is not even clear what is code is supposed to do.

Comment: I am a noob in java...anyway thanks for helping out guys

Comment: Welcome, @user3682031, to Stack Overflow. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). After that you will be able to ask much more well received question and get better help faster.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if(sathya1.nextInt(addition){
```

makes no sense.  It's like saying "if 12".  The same goes for the other lines.  In addition, you're missing a closing `)`, among lots of other problems.

Comment: Please enlighten me

Comment: You'll have to be more specific with your question.

Comment: @user3682031 This is not programming school super basics are taught. There are zillions of resources out there that explain such things!

Comment: its a program to calculate basic arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BasicArithmetic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    //create a scanner for keyboard input
    Scanner sathya1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    //ask user for the operation to be used
    System.out.print("Please enter the corresponding number to be used \n(1)for Addition,(2)for Subtraction,(3)for Multiplication,(4)for Division:");
    int enteredNumber = sathya1.nextInt();

    //get the two numbers to be used
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
    float x = sathya1.nextFloat();
    float y = sathya1.nextFloat();

    //arithmetic operations of the two numbers
    float addition = x+y;
    float subtraction = x-y;
    float multiplication =x*y;
    float division = x/y;

    //if..else statement
    if(enteredNumber==1)
    {
    System.out.println("The sum of the two number is "+addition);
    }
    else if(enteredNumber==2)
    {
    System.out.println("The subtraction of the two number is "+subtraction);
    }
    else if(enteredNumber==3)
    {
    System.out.println("The product of the two number is "+multiplication);
    }
    else if(enteredNumber==4)
    {
    System.out.println("The quotient of the two number is "+division);
    }
    else
    {
     System.out.println("Please enter the correct corresponding number");
    }
    }





}
```